# Mistake computing a $4\times 4$ determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I want to compute the determinant of the matrix
$
\left( \begin{matrix} 2 & -8 & 6 & 8\\ 3 & -9 & 5 & 10 \\ -3 & 0 & 1 & -2 \\ 1 & -4 & 0 & 6 \end{matrix} \right)\,
$.

I use elimination in order to transform the matrix into a triangular one. I perform the following row operations:

1. Swap $(row1)$ and $(row4)$
   $$
   \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & -4 & 0 & 6 \\ 3 & -9 & 5 & 10 \\ -3 & 0 & 1 & -2 \\ 2 & -8 & 6 & 8 \end{matrix} \right)\,.
   $$
2. $-3(row1)+(row2)$, $3(row1)+(row3)$ and $-2(row1)+(row4)$
   $$
   \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & -4 & 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 3 & 5 & -8 \\ 0 & -12 & 1 & 16 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 & -4 \end{matrix} \right)\,.
   $$
3. $4(row2)+(row3)$
   $$
   \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & -4 & 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 3 & 5 & -8 \\ 0 & 0 & 21 & -16 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 & -4 \end{matrix} \right)\,.
   $$
4. Swap $(row3)$ and $(row4)$
   $$
   \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & -4 & 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 3 & 5 & -8 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 & -4 \\ 0 & 0 & 21 & -16 \end{matrix} \right)\,.
   $$
5. $-{21\over 6}(row3)+(row4)$
   $$
   \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & -4 & 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 3 & 5 & -8 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 & -4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \end{matrix} \right)\,.
   $$

After elimination, since there are no zero rows, I multiply the pivots of each row (elements on the diagonal) and also multiply by $(-1)^{\text{number of row swaps}}$. The result following these steps is $-36$, but the actual result is $36$. Can anyone see the mistake?

**EDIT**: The actual determinant is $-36$. Probably I made a mistake when I checked the result in Mathematica.

Comment: The determinant is $-36$. Where did you get 36? However, I think that in general you should count the difference between the positions of the rows, not the number of swaps; e.g., when you swap row 1 and row 4, the value is $4-1=3$. Each time you make a swap, multiply by $(-1)^n$ where $n$ is the difference. So you should multiply $-36$ by $(-1)^3 \cdot (-1)^1$ to get $-36$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news! The actual result is $-36$. :)